# R ggplot2: add kruskal Wallis and pairwise Wilcoxon test to boxplots with multiple groups/subgroups within each group and facet

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, kruskal-wallis, pairwise.wilcox.test

I am trying to add kruskal Wallis and pairwise Wilcoxon test to the figure to show which groups are significant different, but I have multiple groups/subgroups within each group and facet which makes it complicated.

Here is the R code by using iris dataset as an example, the idea is to perform Kruskal.test across different treatments (A, B, C) for different variables (Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, Petal.Width) per species, and also wilcox.test pairwise between them:

```
rm(list=ls(all=TRUE)); cat('\014') # clear workspace
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(viridis) 
library(rstatix)

data(iris)
iris$treatment <- rep(c("A","B","C"), length(iris$Species)/3)
mydf <- gather(iris,Variable,value,Sepal.Length:Petal.Width)
# change number to create more difference
mydf[mydf$treatment=="B",]$value <- mydf[mydf$treatment=="B",]$value*1.2
#mydf[mydf$treatment=="C",]$value <- mydf[mydf$treatment=="C",]$value+0.3

# do pairwise Wilcoxon test for pairwise comparisons between groups
df_wilcox <- mydf %>%
  group_by(Species,Variable) %>%
  pairwise_wilcox_test(value ~ treatment) %>%
  add_y_position(step.increase = 0.02)

# do Kruskal Wallis test to see whether or not there is statistically significant difference between three or more groups
df_kw <- compare_means(value ~ treatment, mydf, group.by = c("Species","Variable"), method="kruskal") 

# plot boxplot with wilcoxon and kruskal test results 
P <- ggplot(data=mydf,
            aes(x=treatment, y=value, fill=Variable))+
  stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar")+geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA)+
  facet_wrap(~Species,nrow=1)+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=12),axis.title=element_text(size=16),plot.title=element_text(size=20)) +
  theme(strip.text = element_text(size=14))+
  scale_fill_viridis(discrete = TRUE) +
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Variable"))+
  stat_pvalue_manual(df_wilcox,color ="Variable",step.group.by="Variable",tip.length = 0,step.increase = 0.02)
  #stat_pvalue_manual(df_wilcox,color ="Variable",step.group.by="Variable",tip.length = 0,step.increase = 0.02,hide.ns=T) #hide non-significant

# change legend title and wilcoxon test color  
ggpar(P,legend.title = "Wilcoxon test",palette = c("#440154FF","#3B528BFF","#21908CFF","#FDE725FF"))
```

This produces the following plot:
[image: 1]

To improve the figure, I want to:

1. automatic add Kruskal test result from 'df_kw' as text to the figure as well and only show significant p-value (e.g. KW(petal.length) p = 0.003)
2. make the wilcoxon line between treatment (e.g. "A", "B", "C") for different variable (e.g. Petal/Speal Length/Width) looks neat (e.g. all on top of the boxplot with consistent line space)
3. make the color of wilcoxon test line same as the color of boxplot (now the 'ggpar' don't always work if I hide non-significant, when the wilcoxon test variable is less than the actual variable)

I am stuck here and wondering anyone has a solution? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I can answer the first part of your question regarding how to add the pvalues labels to the plot automatically. One way to do that is to combine `mydf` and`df_kw` so that `df_kw` includes all of the same columns as `mydf`. here I do that using the `data.table` package like this:

```
setDT(mydf); setDT(df_kw) # convert to data.tables by reference

df_kw <- mydf[df_kw, mult = "first", on = c("Variable", "Species"), nomatch=0L] #creates data table with the same columns as mydf
df_kw <- df_kw[df_kw$p < 0.05,] #removes non-significant values
```

Then you can add the labels automatically using `geom_text`. I would generate a character vector of values to position the labels like this first:

```
y_lab_placement <-  c(sort(rep(seq(max(mydf$value)*1.25, by = -0.35, length.out = length(unique(mydf$Variable))),
                                length(unique(mydf$Species))), decreasing = T)) # creates y values of where to place the labels
y_lab_placement <- y_lab_placement[1:nrow(df_kw)] # adjusts length of placements to the length of significant values
```

Then I would add this line to your ggplot to add the labels:

```
geom_text(data = df_kw, aes(x = 2 , y = y_lab_placement, label = c(paste(Variable, "KW p ~" , round(p, 5)))))+ #adds labels to the plot based on your data
```

Here is your entire code block including these editions.

```
rm(list=ls(all=TRUE)); cat('\014') # clear workspace
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(viridis) 
library(rstatix)
library(data.table) # used in creating combined data table

data(iris)
iris$treatment <- rep(c("A","B","C"), length(iris$Species)/3)
mydf <- gather(iris,Variable,value,Sepal.Length:Petal.Width)
# change number to create more difference
mydf[mydf$treatment=="B",]$value <- mydf[mydf$treatment=="B",]$value*1.2
#mydf[mydf$treatment=="C",]$value <- mydf[mydf$treatment=="C",]$value+0.3

# do pairwise Wilcoxon test for pairwise comparisons between groups
df_wilcox <- mydf %>%
  group_by(Species,Variable) %>%
  pairwise_wilcox_test(value ~ treatment) %>%
  add_y_position(step.increase = 0.02)

# do Kruskal Wallis test to see whether or not there is statistically significant difference between three or more groups
df_kw <- compare_means(value ~ treatment, mydf, group.by = c("Species","Variable"), method="kruskal") 

setDT(mydf); setDT(df_kw) # convert to data.tables by reference

df_kw <- mydf[df_kw, mult = "first", on = c("Variable", "Species"), nomatch=0L] #creates data table with the same columns as mydf
df_kw <- df_kw[df_kw$p < 0.05,] #removes non-significant values 

# plot boxplot with wilcoxon and kruskal test results 
y_lab_placement <-  c(sort(rep(seq(max(mydf$value)*1.25, by = -0.35, length.out = length(unique(mydf$Variable))),
                                length(unique(mydf$Species))), decreasing = T)) # creates y values of where to place the labels
y_lab_placement <- y_lab_placement[1:nrow(df_kw)] # adjusts length of placements to the length of significant values

P <- ggplot(data=mydf,
            aes(x=treatment, y=value, fill=Variable))+
  stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar")+geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA)+
  facet_wrap(~Species,nrow=1)+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=12),axis.title=element_text(size=16),plot.title=element_text(size=20)) +
  theme(strip.text = element_text(size=14))+
  scale_fill_viridis(discrete = TRUE) +
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Variable"))+
  geom_text(data = df_kw, aes(x = 2 , y = y_lab_placement, label = c(paste(Variable, "KW p ~" , round(p, 5)))))+ #adds labels to the plot based on your data
  stat_pvalue_manual(df_wilcox,color ="Variable",step.group.by="Variable",tip.length = 0,step.increase = 0.02)
#stat_pvalue_manual(df_wilcox,color ="Variable",step.group.by="Variable",tip.length = 0,step.increase = 0.02,hide.ns=T) #hide non-significant

# change legend title and wilcoxon test color  
ggpar(P,legend.title = "Wilcoxon test",palette = c("#440154FF","#3B528BFF","#21908CFF","#FDE725FF"))
```

[image: Here is the final image including the labels]